# How to implement CSRF protection in PlayFramework 2.1.x (Scala)?

Tags: security, scala, csrf, playframework-2.1

I need to implement a protection against CSRF attack in a Play 2.1.x (Scala) application. I saw that there is a filter play.filters.csrf.CSRFFilter but could not find enough documentation on using it. Other modules (eg https://github.com/orefalo/play2-authenticitytoken) appear to be obsolete / not maintained.

Do I need to create those measures manually?

Comment: Are there any applications of CSRF besides breaking authentication? If not this might just be specific to the authentication mechanism you are using. I am not sure if this is all, but one thing that can be done against CSRF is starting a new session at login time, even if there is a pre-existing session without authentication.

Answer (score 3):

The article Marco quoted is handy, but I prefer to apply a global CSRF filter to *all* my forms as it seems cleaner and involves less code.

See here: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.2.x/ScalaCsrf

Comment: The main problem is that this feature change radically from 2.0 to 2.1 and 2.2 too...

Answer (score 2):

I have found this [interesting article](http://nickcarroll.me/2013/02/11/protect-your-play-application-with-the-csrf-filter/).
This definitively answer to my question.